Running into this Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
I have been trying to learn Springboot hands on through a tutorial
I am trying to run my springboot application with springboot version 3.2.4. But I am running into this error as seen in the stacktrace below:
2024-07-10 22:41:17 INFO  [main] c.m.p.t.t.k.s.TwitterToKafkaServiceApplication - Starting TwitterToKafkaServiceApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 2932 (/Users/pavanvasan/Backend Projects Walkthrough/microservices-pavan/twitter-to-kafka-service/target/classes started by pavanvasan in /Users/pavanvasan/Backend Projects Walkthrough/microservices-pavan)
2024-07-10 22:41:17 INFO  [main] c.m.p.t.t.k.s.TwitterToKafkaServiceApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-10 22:41:18 WARN  [main] o.s.c.a.AnnotationTypeMapping - Support for convention-based annotation attribute overrides is deprecated and will be removed in Spring Framework 6.2. Please annotate the following attributes in @org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry with appropriate @AliasFor declarations: [proxyTargetClass]
2024-07-10 22:41:18 WARN  [main] o.s.b.w.r.c.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
2024-07-10 22:41:18 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-10 22:41:18 ERROR [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:805)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at com.microservices.pavan.twitter.to.kafka.service.TwitterToKafkaServiceApplication.main(TwitterToKafkaServiceApplication.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Pointcut
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.initBeanFactory(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setBeanFactory(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 21 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried everything I could think of. I tried to find out dependencies using the mvn dependency:tree command and it showed no dependencies.
I tried to exclude the same thing in the application.properties file as well with this line:
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration
Tried to exclude dependencies wherever possible, as seen below:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

The above is one example which I am using for the multiple modules that I have in my microservice
FYI I am using intellij IDEA CE v2023.2.4 as my IDE and I am using Java 17
This is the github link of my repository: https://github.com/PLSV/microservices-pavan
More details in this ChatGPT link: https://chatgpt.com/share/94d0310d-e08d-4816-a34e-3d38a194dbee

You are trying to learn Springboot with a multi-module Kafka project? Tough!

Why are you trying to exclude AOP from the project? It's one of the core Spring technologies.

As per @M. Prokhorov, why are you excluding aspectjweaver? aspectjweaver is the jar that contains org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut.
Surely the pom of twitter-to-kafka service should have the following added rather than excluded from the spring-boot-starter dependencies.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>


I had to add aspectjweaver to all my modules to solve the issue. Thanks for your inputs on this John Williams and M Prokhorov
